# How to check whether a valid session exists or not with a given jsession id

Tags: java, php, servlets, single-sign-on

Actually I have a requirement.

1. (Site1) https://myappdomain.it/...  This is my app which is using spring and hibernate and it is build on tomcat server.
2. (Site2) https://wiki.myappdomain.com/docs/........ This is the documentation website which contains the documentation information of the above app and this website is developed based on php.

What here I want to do is if a user login to Site1 successfully, then he will click on docs link in this Site2. Then the url will be redirected to Site1. If a user try to open the docs site with out logging into Site1. then i should show access denied.

### My approach for solution:

when a user clicks on docs link, then i will send a jsessionid of Site1 to Site2. There in php site i will make a request to first site saying that to check session availability by sending the requested jsessionid as a parameter. I will write a method in Site1 which checks whether a valid session exists or not based on given jsession id. If session is valid i will send response status 200 ok. Else i will send response status 401 unauthorised access. if response status is ok, then php site will show documentation page else it shows unauthorized access.

So here my doubt is "Am I going in correct way, and in spring or java `servlet` context, can i get session by a given jsessionId." Is this possible to do?

Comment: Passing JSESSIONID as a URL parameter can be a security issue, as browsers will cache the visited URLs. You could use cookies instead. Read up about SSO (Single-Sign-on) on the web.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I think SSO will work to handle my requirement.